# How to isolate the main text of a webpage in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to save the text from a webpage and use another function to summarize the text. The problem is that my summaries end up having weird text from various things in the webpage like ads. I'm using BeautifulSoup to extract the text. Here's the code for the text extraction:

```
def web_crawler():
    userinput = str(input("Enter a valid Web Page URL: "))
    url = urllib.urlopen(userinput).read()
    #add exception here for internet connection not avalaible
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.decode('utf8'))
    [s.extract() for s in soup('script')]   #remove javascriptlinks
    [s.extract() for s in soup('style')]    #remove css
    [s.extract() for s in soup('a')]    # remove links
    title = str(soup.title).strip("<title>")
    title = title.strip("</")
    htmlText = soup.get_text()
    htmlText = ' '.join(htmlText.split())   #remove unnecessary whitspace
    textFile = open("textFile.txt", mode = "w", encoding = "utf8")
    textFile.write(htmlText)    #save text file to use in memory friendly version
    textFile.close()
    #for now return the title query and the article text
    return (title, htmlText)
```

For example I want to summarize the text content of this webpage:

[image]

And when I do the summary of the text, I get text from the ads and features on the side. Is there a way I can grab only the main body's text from the webpage?

Comment: Have you tried figuring out which elements contain the text you want?

Comment: This will be very difficult if you want to do it for any webpage at all, as they are all different. If it is for pages on a specific website (e.g. articles on a specific news site) then you could look at the page source and try and find the `class` or `id` of the element containing the text.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Oh I see. Most of the text I need is going to be in the <p> tags. bs4 should have a function to extract the text from a particular tag right?

Comment: I was expecting something like "that div on the left, that has an id of xxx", but I suppose that could be made to work as well...

Comment: @DanielGibbs I'm going to attempt to do it for any website, using the findAll function on <p> tags. That might exclude the unwanted text. If not, I'll make it website specific and use div ids